# PHP execute query if all preg_matches are good

Tags: php, sql, preg-match

I have a script that catches everything wrong what users filled in in a form.
Now, if they fill everything in right, the query should execute.

This is my script:

```
<?php

if(preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $wachtwoord) === 0)
{
echo '<font>Wachtwoord moet minstens 8 tekens lang zijn, een kleine letter, grote letter én cijfer bevatten.<br><font>';
}
else 
{
$wachtwoord = 'goed';
}

if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{10}+$/", $telefoonnummer) === 0)
{
echo '<font>Het telefoonnummer moet 10 cijfers bevatten.<br><font>';
}
else 
{
$telefoonnummer = 'goed';
}

if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$/", $gbdatum) === 0)
{
echo '<font>Geboorte datum moet op dit formaat ingevoerd worden: JJJJ-MM-DD<br><font>';
}
else 
{
$gbdatum = 'goed';
}

if(preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}$/i", $email) === 0)
{
echo '<font>Email moet hier op lijken: email@provider.com<br><font>';
}
else 
{
$email = 'goed';
}

if(preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/", $voornaam) === 0)
{
echo '<font>Voornaam is niet geldig ingevoerd, heeft u een hoofdletter gebruikt?<br><font>';
}
else 
{
$voornaam = 'goed';
}

if(preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/", $achternaam) === 0)
{
echo '<font>Achternaam is niet geldig ingevoerd, heeft u een hoofdletter gebruikt?<br><font>';
}
else 
{
$achternaam = 'goed';
}

if ($geslacht == '') 
{
echo '<font>U heeft uw geslacht niet aangegeven<br><font>';
}
else 
{
$geslacht = 'goed';
}

if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+\ +[0-9]+$/", $adres) === 0)
{
echo '<font>Adres is verkeerd ingevoerd<br><font>';
}


if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/", $woonplaats) === 0)
{
echo '<font>Woonplaats is verkeerd ingevoerd<br><font>';
}

if (ABOVE STATEMENTS DONT APPLY)
{
mysql_query($query);
echo "<font>Uw registratie is succesvol verwerkt <br>Log <a href='login.php' MEDIA=screen>hier</a> in<font>";
}

?>
```

Now what do I put in in    `if (ABOVE STATEMENTS DONT APPLY)` so it will run the script IF everything is put in the form right.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

You can ignore

```
else 
{
$geslacht = 'goed';
}
```

That was something I tried in the last IF. (like if ($1 && $2 = 'goed') but that didn't work anyway.

Comment: Set a `$complete=true;` at the top, on every error-condition, just run `$complete = false;`, and check in the end what state `$complete` is in (`if( $complete){mysql(....);}`). And btw: `font` tags are ancient relics best forgotten....

Comment: This actually did the trick, how can I mark your comment as the right answer?

Comment: You can't, I'd say @Fluffeh's answer is the same one, mark that one in that case ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a simple catch-all boolean.

At the start add in

```
$canContinue=true;
```

right after `<?php`

Then, in your conditional checks, if any of them fails change the boolean to `false` like this:

```
if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$/", $gbdatum) === 0)
{
echo '<font>Geboorte datum moet op dit formaat ingevoerd worden: JJJJ-MM-DD<br><font>';
$canContinue=false;
}
```

If you include that `$canContinue=false;` in all of the statements, you can have your last if statement like this:

```
if ($canContinue)
{
mysql_query($query);
echo "<font>Uw registratie is succesvol verwerkt <br>Log <a href='login.php' MEDIA=screen>hier</a> in<font>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to create an errors array at the top of your file. Then, if a field was not filled in correctly, add an error to this array. If this array ends up being empty, you can execute the query. The advantage to this is that you also immediately have a clean, simple and efficient way to output the potential errors.

```
$errors = array();

if ( invalid password ) {
    $errors[] = 'invalid password';
}

if ( invalid phone number ) {
    $errors[] = 'invalid phone number';
}

if ( empty($errors) ) {
    // execute query
} else {
    echo '<ul><li>', implode('</li><li>', $errors), '</li></ul>';
}
```

The way you print your errors can be done in a wide variety of ways. What I did above was just an example.